# C bubble sort by pointers for array of strings not running inner loop?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers, bubble-sort

I'm getting practice with C pointers, and have written the following bubble sort code to sort an array of strings. I'm super confused as to why it's not working, as I feel like everything is referenced correctly? On gcc I get a compiler warning for the second loop that I'm comparing an int to a pointer, but I'm doing almost the exact same thing on the prior line so I'm confused why it's not quite working.

```
167 void sortList(char **wds, int sz) {
168     char **i, **j, *tmp;
169     for (i=wds; i < wds+sz-1; i++ ) {
170         for (j=wds; j < wds+sz-i-1; j++) {
171             printf("here\n");
172             if (strcmp(*j, *(j+1)) > 0) {
173                 tmp = *j;
174                 *j = *(j+1);
175                 *(j+1) = tmp;
176             }
177         }
178     }
180     return;
```

In my main function, I have my array to sort declared as follows:

```
char *arr[] = {"This", "is", "a", "test"};
```

and I call my function as

```
sortList(arr, 4);
```

That  print statement isn't ever being printed, so I'm assuming the loop isn't running.

Pardon the pun, but can anyone point me in the right direction of the bug?

Comment: Doesn't  the compiler warn you about `j < wds+sz-i-1;`? On the left is a pointer, on the right is an integer (from the subtraction of pointers).

Comment: @WeatherVane I mentioned this in the post...it does, but I'm not sure how that comes about? I'm doing a super similar thing in the first loop and don't get an error. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: You say "I'm doing almost the exact same" but in the first loop you are not subtracting a pointer from a pointer.

Comment: How would I keep the loop behavior without subtracting a pointer from a pointer? Or could I just add j back in? @WeatherVane

Comment: It would be less of a tangle if you work with array indices instead.

Comment: Certainly, but I'm trying to use pointers for practice. Is this general idea correct or should I just scrap that?

Comment: It doesn't usually make sense to use pointers for iteration when the size is known, as it is here.